# How to get anchor ID from Table row using onlick events

Tags: jquery

```
 rows = "<tr>"
  + "<td> <a onclick='getDetailsByID(" + item.ID+ ")'><i class='material-icons' style='font-size:15px' >mode_edit</i></a> </td>"
  + "<td>" + item.GROUPNAME + "</td>"
  + "</tr>";
  $('#tblAccountgrup tbody').append(rows);
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is numeric then you can continue to do

```
<a onclick='getDetailsByID(" + item.ID+ ")'>
```

otherwise you need

```
<a onclick=\"getDetailsByID('" + item.ID+ "')\">
```

but I recommend using data attributes

```
<a class="details" data-id =\""+item.ID+"\">
```

and delegate

```
$('#tblAccountgrup').on("click","a.details",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getDetailsByID(this.dataset.id)
})
```